# Reapp reactjs custom styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

I am enjoying using Reapp, it's great technology, well done.

My question is about custom styling.

I understand if I create my own custom styles (extending your theme),

I can do something like the below

/app/theme/styles/Card.js

```
export default {
    self: {
        border: "solid 2px #000",
        color: "#777"
    }
 };
```

In the Home.jsx

```
<Card className="success" title="Person">
    Hello
</Card>
```

How can I adjust the styles in in Card.js (style), to use a class called .success

eg:

```
export default {
  self: {
    border: "solid 2px #000",
    color: "#777",
    success: {
       background: "#333"
    }
  }
};
```